# SSIS to many open Connections

Tags: ssis, connection

im new to SSIS and have an error see below.

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: So do you actually open more than 255 connections? If so then perhaps you need to have multiple packages that run in sequence

Comment: not as i'm aware of , i have 1 connection in the package i'm using. is there any way to check?

Comment: You could click "View" and select "Code". This will give you the XML which you can search for the various connections. Is there a loop in your solution? A screen shot of the control flow might help!

Comment: My guess would be that you've got a loop somewhere - perhaps an unintended recursion.  Without seeing your package, though, we're all kinda guessing.